# Можно ли с помощью ffmpeg сжимать изображения (jpg, png ...) ? Как?

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg

Умеет ли ffmpeg сжимать изображения? Если да, то подскажите команду для уменьшения именно размера файла.

Answer (score 2):

Если нет острой необходимости «пилить дрелью и сверлить лобзиком», то можно использовать следующий скрипт с использованием инструментов, специально написанных для работы с неподвижными изображениями (потребуются пакеты imagemagick, pngcrush, optipng, trimage и libjpeg-turbo-progs; подходящие вам проценты качества для JPEG установите самостоятельно):

```
#! /bin/bash

if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 filename"
    exit 1;
fi

if [ ! -f "$1" ]; then
    echo "$1 is not a file"
    exit 1;
fi

TYPE=`identify "$1" | grep -E -o 'JPEG|GIF|PNG'`
OLD=`stat -c %s "$1"`

case "$TYPE" in
    JPEG)
        convert -strip -interlace Plane -quality 90% "$1" "$1.new" && mv "$1" "$1.old" && mv "$1.new" "$1"
        jpegtran -copy none -optimize -perfect -progressive -outfile "$1.tmp" "$1"
        jpegtran -copy none -optimize -perfect -outfile "$1.tmq" "$1"
        if [ -f "$1.tmp" -a -f "$1.tmq" ]; then
            S_PROG=`stat -c %s "$1.tmp"`
            S_NORM=`stat -c %s "$1.tmq"`
            if [ $S_PROG -ge $S_NORM ]; then
                mv -f "$1.tmq" "$1"
                rm -f "$1.tmp"
            else
                mv -f "$1.tmp" "$1"
                rm -f "$1.tmq"
            fi;
        fi
    ;;
GIF)
    gifsicle -O2 -b "$1"
;;

PNG)
    pngcrush -q -rem alla -fix "$1" "$1.tmp"
    if [ -f "$1.tmp" ]; then
        mv -f "$1.tmp" "$1"
    fi;
    optipng -zc6-9 -zm1-9 -zs0-3 -f0-5 -q -fix "$1"
    advpng -z -4 -q "$1"
;;

esac
```